# Solve the initial value problem $u_x^2u_t-1=0$, $u(x,0)=x$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem $u_x^2u_t-1=0$, $u(x,0)=x$.

This becomes $u_x^2u_t=1$, $u(x,0)=x$.

I was thinking that this was a nonlinear wave equation at first, but the $x$ component is multiplying the $t$ component. My textbook has been going through 'let $p$ be this and $q$ be that'. Am I supposed to set $p=u_x$ and $q=u_t$? But where do I go from there?

I don't know where to start on this, let alone where to go. Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$u_x^2u_t-1=0$

$u_t-\dfrac{1}{u_x^2}=0$

$u_{tx}+\dfrac{2u_{xx}}{u_x^3}=0$

Let $v=u_x$ ,

Then $v_t+\dfrac{2v_x}{v^3}=0$ with $v(x,0)=1$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{dv}{ds}=0$ , letting $v(0)=v_0$ , we have $v=v_0$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=\dfrac{2}{v^3}=\dfrac{2}{v_0^3}$ , letting $x(0)=f(v_0)$ , we have $x=\dfrac{2s}{v_0^3}+f(v_0)=\dfrac{2t}{v^3}+f(v)$ , i.e. $v=F\left(x-\dfrac{2t}{v^3}\right)$

$v(x,0)=1$ :

$F(x)=1$

$\therefore v=1$

$u_x=1$

$u(x,t)=x+g(t)$

$u_t=g_t(t)$

$\therefore g_t(t)=1$

$g(t)=t+C$

$\therefore u(x,t)=x+t+C$

$u(x,0)=x$ :

$C=0$

$\therefore u(x,t)=x+t$